# Как распараллелить вычисления в цикле с помощью async

Tags: c++, visual-c++, асинхронность, распараллеливание

Сначала запускается функция mult_karacuba, затем из неё идет асинхронный вызов функции multi. В моем понимании, async должен распределить доступные потоки, но время вычисления не изменяется.

```
void multi(vector<vector<int>>& x, vector<vector<int>>& y, vector<vector<int>>& res, int len, int n, int size, int i) {

    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        n = max(x[i].size(), y[j].size());
        size = 1;
        while (size < n) // выравнивание векторов
            size <<= 1;
        x[i].resize(size);
        y[j].resize(size);


        res[i + j] = addvec(res[i + j], karatsuba_mul(x[i], y[j]));

    }
}

vector<vector<int>> mult_karacuba(vector<vector<int>>& x, vector<vector<int>>& y) { // умножение полиномов стандартным методом

    size_t len = x.size();
    auto len1 = len;
    vector<vector<int>> res(2 * len);
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int size = 0;
    auto n = 0;

    for (auto i = 0; i < len; ++i) { // основной цикл умножения

        std::async(std::launch::async, multi, x, y, std::ref(res), len, n, size, i);

    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: @Abyx, зачем мне работать с future, если я изменяю значение результата непосредственно в функции. Наверное, я не понимаю как это вообще работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::async` возвращает `std::future` который ждет в своем деструкторе.

У Вас в коде `future` разрушается сразу же после вызова async, никакой параллельности не получается.

Правильно - это положить результаты std::async в контейнер.

```
vector<future<void>> f;
for (auto i = 0; i < len; ++i) f.push_back(async(multi, x, ...));
```

Если исключений не ожидается, то можно ничего не делать, ожидание произойдет в деструкторе `f`.
Либо можно перебрать все `future` и вызвать у них `get()`, который будет бросать исключения.

Comment: есть функция типа void, то она ничего не возвращает и что тогда записывается в элемент контейнера?